# jquery resizable handles - are they supposed to work?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

Ok, So I'm a bit lost on this. jQuery UI documentation states that on resizable i can have visible handles which as i understand are visible icons/pictures (do I understand this correctly?)

> If specified as a string, should be a comma-split list of any of the following: 'n, e, s, w, >ne, se, sw, nw, all'. The necessary handles will be auto-generated by the plugin.

So I should have handles all over my object if I specify 'all' ? If so, it does not seem to work--I only have something visible on 'se' corner.

Now looking at [jQuery UI resizable source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js#L110), it seems that this is the only way it is supossed to work :

```
if ('se' == handle) {
   axis.addClass('ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se');
};
```

Am I missing something? Can I create them on my own?

Answer (score 0):

That code is telling the widget to only bother setting up a nice icon for the SE handle, if they're automatically generated. It's still actually creating the handles as a small, invisible box in each corner which can be dragged, just without any icon (the jQuery UI iconset actually doesn't have any other similar handles).

Refer to [the API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) for how to attach them to your own DOM objects, which you can easily customise the appearance of. Quick example:

```
$('#targetToMakeResizable').resizable({handles : { ne : ".jquerySelectorForNEHandle", sw: ".jquerySelectorForSWHandle" }, aspectRatio : true});
```

Alternatively, you can just override the base css for .ui-resizable-handle.ui-resizable-{direction} with your own settings.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QhjTA/) to demonstrate both methods. Note that rotating the icon in the way I've done it is probably not going to work in every browser.